# Data elements in Python

Tags: python, arrays, slice

I'm a bit stuck trying to understand this line of code.

```
women_only_stats = data[0::,4] == "female"
```

I'm confused with the part of data. What exactly does the double colon mean with the comma 4 next to it?

Comment: `[start:stop:step]`, where the comma comes from?

Comment: i know the start and stop procedure its just i dont know the difference between [::] and using [:]

Comment: As far as I know, that's a syntax error. The comma should not be there.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a syntax error, and probably isn't even a mistake.  We'd need to see `data` to be sure. Numpy arrays, among others, accept a tuple of slices as an index, so it's certainly not impossible.

See [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html) for an introduction to numpy indexing.

The `0::` part is basically the same as `:` or `::`, at least if we're using the standard slice interpretation.  (Remember that slice objects can be made of many types, and so things like `"A":10:(1,2)` are perfectly valid syntactically-- it's the object's responsibility to decide how it wants to handle that input.)

I suspect that data is a numpy array looking something like

```
>>> data
array([[1, 2, 5, 12, 'male'],
       [1, 2, 5, 12, 'female'],
       [1, 2, 5, 12, 'female']], dtype=object)
>>> data[:,4]
array(['male', 'female', 'female'], dtype=object)
```

`:,4`, or `::,4`, or `0::,4`, all mean "give me every value along axis 0 (the rows), and column #4".  We can then do a vectorized comparison:

```
>>> data[:,4] == "female"
array([False,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Finally, we can use that to filter `data`:

```
>>> female_only_stats = data[:,4] == "female"
>>> data[female_only_stats]
array([[1, 2, 5, 12, 'female'],
       [1, 2, 5, 12, 'female']], dtype=object)
```